# SSL with Apache Nifi not working

Tags: ssl, ldap, apache-nifi

I have been working on this problem for quite some time and I would like answers and suggestions from you guys on the issue I am facing. I am trying to get my Nifi standalone instance on my server and basically my requirement is LDAP authenitcation, for that i have read some documents and found need to setup SSL first so i have followed this
[link](http://www.batchiq.com/nifi-configuring-ssl-auth.html)
but i am getting the below error.

```
2017-01-20 23:39:12,603 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.authorization.FileAuthorizer Authorizations file loaded at Fri Jan 20 23:39:12 HKT 2017
2017-01-20 23:39:59,327 INFO [NiFi Web Server-44] o.a.n.w.a.c.IllegalStateExceptionMapper java.lang.IllegalStateException: Kerberos ticket login not supported by this NiFi.. Returning Conflict response.
2017-01-20 23:39:59,331 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-44] o.a.n.w.a.c.IllegalStateExceptionMapper
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Kerberos ticket login not supported by this NiFi.
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.AccessResource.createAccessTokenFromTicket(AccessResource.java:349) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:51) [jetty-servlets-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger.doFilter(RequestLogger.java:66) [classes/:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.apache.nifi.web.filter.TimerFilter.doFilter(TimerFilter.java:51) [classes/:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [jetty-security-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:186) [jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) [jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
2017-01-20 23:39:59,556 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-55] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Checking secure context token: null
2017-01-20 23:39:59,557 INFO [NiFi Web Server-55] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Attempting request for (EMAILADDRESS=07anis@gmail.com, CN=admin, OU=EDM, O=XXX, L=HK, ST=HK, C=HK) GET https://hklpadhod07:7443/nifi-api/flow/current-user (source ip: 10.112.194.113)
2017-01-20 23:39:59,559 INFO [NiFi Web Server-55] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for EMAILADDRESS=07anis@gmail.com, CN=admin, OU=EDM, O=XXX, L=HK, ST=HK, C=HK
2017-01-20 23:39:59,559 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-55] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Checking secure context token: EMAILADDRESS=07anis@gmail.com, CN=admin, OU=EDM, O=XXX, L=HK, ST=HK, C=HK
2017-01-20 23:39:59,559 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-55] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Checking secure context token: EMAILADDRESS=07anis@gmail.com, CN=admin, OU=EDM, O=XXX, L=HK, ST=HK, C=HK
2017-01-20 23:39:59,560 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-55] o.a.n.w.s.a.NiFiAnonymousUserFilter SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'EMAILADDRESS=07anis@gmail.com, CN=admin, OU=EDM, O=XXX, L=HK, ST=HK, C=HK'
2017-01-20 23:39:59,571 INFO [NiFi Web Server-55] o.a.n.w.a.c.AccessDeniedExceptionMapper EMAILADDRESS=07anis@gmail.com, CN=admin, OU=EDM, O=XXX, L=HK, ST=HK, C=HK does not have permission to access the requested resource. Returning Forbidden response.
2017-01-20 23:39:59,572 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-55] o.a.n.w.a.c.AccessDeniedExceptionMapper
org.apache.nifi.authorization.AccessDeniedException: Unknown user with identity 'EMAILADDRESS=07anis@gmail.com, CN=admin, OU=EDM, O=XXX, L=HK, ST=HK, C=HK'.
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.FlowResource.authorizeFlow(FlowResource.java:226) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.apache.nifi.web.api.FlowResource.getCurrentUser(FlowResource.java:312) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) ~[jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:1.19]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:51) [jetty-servlets-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger.doFilter(RequestLogger.java:66) [classes/:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0
```

and my authorizers.xml

```
<authorizer>
        <identifier>file-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAuthorizer</class>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">"EMAILADDRESS=07anis@gmail.com,CN=admin,OU=EDM,O=XXX,L=HK,ST=HK,C=HK"</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>

        <!-- Provide the identity (typically a DN) of each node when clustered, see above description of Node Identity.
        <property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 2"></property>
        -->
    </authorizer>
```

kindly have a look and advice.

Answer (score 6):

- Stop your NiFi Delete users.xml and authorizations.xml
- Edit authorizers.xml so that the "Initial Admin Identity" matches exactly
  what see in your logs, notice yours has no spaces and the logs do
  have spaces
- Start again